# maven-remote-resources-plugin vs maven-resources-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-resources-plugin, maven-remote-resources

I am creating a multi module maven project and want to keep resources (property files, json) in a separate module. Now to import this resource module in other modules, I have two option - either to use maven-resources-plugin or to use maven-remote-resources-plugin. I already have working code wrt maven-resources-plugin but while searching in internet I found post only on maven-remote-resources-plugin which made me question if I am following maven standards on resources use.
And is it worth to move from maven-resources-plugin to maven-remote-resources-plugin?
Any pointers with respect to this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "...want to keep resources (property files, json) in a separate
>   module"

1. You can use [Maven Remote Resources Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-remote-resources-plugin/)  Of course to bundle your resources in a single JAR that can be used across.

   > This plugin is used to retrieve JARs of resources from remote
   >   repositories, process those resources, and incorporate them into JARs
   >   you build with Maven. A very common use-case is the need to package
   >   certain resources in a consistent way across your organization: at
   >   Apache it is required that every JAR produced contains a copy of the
   >   Apache license and a notice file that references all used software in
   >   a given project.
2. [Maven Resource Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) has its own usage of copying resources within modules when you don't have them located in the default maven path and want to use them explicitly.